# Calling swift Code From Javascript

Tags: javascript, swift, callback

Is it possible to call Swift functions/callbacks from Javascript ? 
In Android it is possible to use JavaVoidCallbacks, is there anything similar in Swift? Right now Im using JavaScriptCore,where i can call javascript functions from Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

Please refer to this Tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/124075/javascriptcore-tutorial

You are interested in the paragraph "Exposing Native Code"

In obj-c is very simple. You can do it just by using your jsContext as a normal dictionary.

```
context[@"functionName"] = ^ <#returnType#> (<#parameters#>) {
    <#Your code#>
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: thanks, but how do i call the swift function from JavaScript? lets say i have a function which gives me hello world in swift. how do i call this fuction from javascript

Comment: As the tutorial explains, first you create the block that calls this swift function, then you add it to your jsContext. After that you call it normally like you would call a function defined directly in javascript through your jsContext.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, the easiest way I found was to create a gateway object in Javascript, using e.g. evaluateScript(), and then adding functions to that object:

```
let gateway = jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("gateway" as NSString)
let p: @convention(block) (Int, Double) -> () = { h, ms in
     return self.swift_method(h, ms)
}
gateway!.setObject(p, forKeyedSubscript: "swift_method" as NSString)
```

After that you can call gateway.swift_method() in Javascript.

Most type conversions are automatic. I have used types Int, Double, String and [Int] as parameter and/or return types in the lambda.

Comment: Your code example looks like in js side. How is x created? Which class is linked with this call? Appreciate your further post if you could provide more codes and information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. When I saw the answers to this Q. I tried to use JavaScriptCore to call Swift methods from the JS side. I could inject Swift or JS methods into JSContext. However, the methods injected into JSContext are not accessible in my case.

I use WKWebView as an HTML viewer in the ViewController in my iOS native app. I use this kind of view controller to present some help information in my app. After several days of struggling, I finally found an alternative way to make Swift and JS interaction happen. The strategy is to use WKScriptMessageHandler as a gateway between Swift and JS. Refer to [this good blog](https://medium.com/swlh/web-to-native-code-communication-on-ios-using-wkscriptmessagehandler-8d307b3847fa) on how to do it in detail. Another blog, [Using WebKit to call WKWebView JavaScript from Swift and Swift from JavaScrip](https://medium.com/rekerrsive/using-webkit-to-call-wkwebview-javascript-from-swift-and-swift-from-javascript-9d9ec593136e)t, provides another example case, which is very useful.

From my experience, `WKScriptMessageHandler` is based on a very elegant structure. Through `WKUserContentController`, you set up a message gateway between JS and Swift. There is This will allow a JS callback to Swift with messages. A delegate of `WKWebViewConfiguration` has to be implemented, my view controller with web view, or my custom class, to receive `JS` message calls with data. The message can take a `JSON` string as a parameter to pass data. On the Swift side, by using a similar `JSContext` syntax like `evaluateJavaScript` to specify JS a function with data.

By the way, I was told that in my case, JavaScriptCore is based on Java virtue machine. There may be performance issue and may pose a security risk. Apple has disabled the feature of JavaScriptCore in WKWebView.

The Xcode in my case is Version 13.4, and Swift is 5.

I have written a blog on this: [Build a Bridge between Swift and JS](https://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.com/2022/08/build-bridge-between-swift-and-js.html)